# How to append data in object and display its content on one page in MongoDB JAVA?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to insert this type of model in like :

```
{
   _id: POST_ID
   title: TITLE_OF_POST, 
   by: POST_BY,
   questions: [ 
      {
         QID:1,
         Question:"text" 
      },
      {
        QID:1,
        Question:"text" 
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to model the above situation using

```
Document document=new Document("topic",topic)
            .append("empid",empid)
            .append("teacher", teacher)
            .append("date",d)
            .append("questions",[
        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {//This is not correct.
                        String string = questions[i];}]);
```

I want to insert questions in object name questions, then display them on one page using for loop on qid then displaying all the questions on one page using `servlet out.println`. I want to select document then iterate over qid and display all questions.

example:

```
Title of Assignment \n
Teacher Name \n
Question 1: Content of question 1. \n
Question 2: Content of Question 2.
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you had any problems you can't get past?

Comment: The above code I have mentioned for creating document doesn't work, there is syntax error.
I don't know how to query and display content of object of object, I want to list all questions on one page.

Comment: What is the error you get on compilation? You should include it in the question.

Comment: The whole program needs to be completed for efficient compilation. The error shown by eclipse in line by line compilation is "Syntax error, delete token".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for creating `Document` instance you are using absolutely wrong Java syntax. 
in Java you can't use something like:

```
.append("questions",[  for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
```

you should create firstly list of questions, and after that use this list while preparing Document instance:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
    put("QID", 1);
    put("Question", "text");
}});
questions.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
    put("QID", 2);
    put("Question", "text");
}});


Document document  = new Document("_id", 1001)
        .append("topic", "topic")
        .append("empid", 5)
        .append("teacher", "teacher")
        .append("date", 555)
        .append("questions", questions);

collection.insertOne(document);
```

for retrieving previously inserted item from collection you could use the following:

```
    Document foundDocument = collection.find(new Document("_id", 1001)).first();
    List<Map> foundQuestions = (List) foundDocument.get("questions");
    for (Map foundQuestion: foundQuestions) {
        Integer qid = (Integer) foundQuestion.get("QID");
        String questionValue = foundQuestion.get("Question").toString();
        System.out.println(qid + " : " + questionValue);
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Can you please answer second part of my question that how can I display content of one document, iterate it over the object questions to display qid and questions on one page? I am able to display list of all documents and their content.

Comment: updated answer with example how to query collection by _id value and get 'questions' list

Comment: Vasiliy Thank you, This solution worked perfectly. Thanks Again. This is the perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: @Vasily Why did you use double brackets {{}}, HashMap<String,Object> ?

Comment: it's just a short version of creating HashMap instance:
`Map<String, Object> question = new HashMap<String, Object>();
question.put("QID", 1);
question.put("Question", "text");
questions.add(question);`
so you could use either example as in this comment or as in the answer.